# what is the cause of google nest hub's answer sdp info don't appear after received the camera's offer sdp response

Tags: webrtc, streaming, action, google-smart-home, sdp

1. The issue is reproduced 100% of the time.
2. we can stream from the same camera in the camera's own app.
3. we have checked the camera's offer sdp response, that's OK.
4. the SupportedStreamProtocols is webRTC.
5. detailed issue:

- the request: "Intent: action.devices.EXECUTE, Command: action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream".
- After the above request, the camera cloud service do respond the correct sdp information, but the answer sdp information that are never received. sometimes, google nest hub will send the "end" action suddenly.

6. interactive data:

- 2023-03-22T13:23:16+0000

> --
> GoogleRequest:{"requestId":"8676804431427309387","inputs":[{"context":{"locale_country":"","locale_language":"sv"},"intent":"action.devices.EXECUTE","payload":{"commands":[{"devices":[{"id":"T8210P6421501817"}],"execution":[{"command":"action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream","params":{"SupportedStreamProtocols":["webrtc"]}}]}]}}]}
> -- Response:{"requestId":"8676804431427309387","payload":{"commands":[{"ids":["T8210P6421501817"],"status":"SUCCESS","states":{"cameraStreamAuthToken":"euGo|r0iL11nuS_aSQPhSNtZlhg","cameraStreamIceServers":"[{"urls":"stun:3.123.109.172:3478"},{"urls":"turn:3.123.109.172:3478?transport=udp","username":"BXe1uTXXg8","credential":"HbdIMOeTVjnWTPVe"}]","cameraStreamSignalingUrl":"https://security-smart-eu.eufylife.com/v1/smart/google/webrtc?sessionId=81e50a34-44ad-4822-b97d-c187625d825c","cameraStreamOffer":"v=0\r\no=- 1679491395464 1679491395464 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=Anker Webrtc
> Stream\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS
> fJpn2\r\nm=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0\r\nc=IN IP4
> 127.0.0.1\r\na=mid:0\r\na=sendonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=ice-ufrag:873o\r\na=ice-pwd:zGGsH/BaHndpznTe70Mvv/\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256
> A9:07:34:CA:F8:6F:12:21:98:12:C9:D1:90:49:90:93:54:E6:6F:08:01:73:2C:81:F8:43:4B:75:BC:89:8D:3C\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtpmap:0
> PCMU/8000\r\na=ssrc:2200340691 cname:wz3l4Gc4\r\na=candidate:1 1 udp
> 2122317823 192.168.68.101 34512 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:2
> 1 udp 2122317567 192.168.32.2 34512 typ host generation
> 0\r\na=candidate:3 1 udp 1686109695 188.150.241.145 34512 typ srflx
> generation 0\r\na=candidate:4 1 udp 8387839 3.123.109.172 55137 typ
> relay generation 0\r\nm=video 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98\r\nc=IN IP4
> 0.0.0.0\r\na=mid:1\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=ice-ufrag:873o\r\na=ice-pwd:zGGsH/BaHndpznTe70Mvv/\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256
> A9:07:34:CA:F8:6F:12:21:98:12:C9:D1:90:49:90:93:54:E6:6F:08:01:73:2C:81:F8:43:4B:75:BC:89:8D:3C\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtpmap:98
> H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98
> nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:98
> level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtcp-fb:98
> ccm fir\r\na=ssrc:1180311490
> cname:riolfAKg\r\n","cameraStreamProtocol":"webrtc"}}]}}
>
> - 2023-03-22T13:23:17  -- {"sessionId":"81e50a34-44ad-4822-b97d-c187625d825c","action":"end","deviceId":"T8210P6421501817","sdp":""}

We desired to find out the root cause of this issue, If anyone can help, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the player logs from your GCP project. If you filter for ‘ClientUpdate’, you will be able to see the logs that the WebRTC player generates on the device. Also, make sure that to ensure that you are receiving an offer SDP from Google and are sending a correctly formed answer SDP back.